# Sending variables between classes

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have a `JFrame` class and a `JPanel` class.
When I click on a button in my `JFrame` my variable addIp take the entered String.

How can I access to this variable in my `JPanel` class ?

Here's my `JFrame` class:

```
 public class Window extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Window();
    }
}

public Window()
{
    this.setSize(1000,400);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setTitle("Assignment2 - CPU temperature");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    container = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());


    north = new JPanel();
    north.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    ip = new JButton ("New");
    north.add(ip, BorderLayout.WEST);
    print = new JButton ("Print");
    north.add(print,BorderLayout.EAST);

    JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();

    centerPanel.add(new JLabel("Time Step (in s): "));
    timeStep = new JTextArea("0.1",1,5);
    centerPanel.add(timeStep);
    start = new JButton("OK");
    stop = new JButton("STOP");
    ListenForButton lForButton = new ListenForButton();
    ip.addActionListener(lForButton);
    centerPanel.add(start);
    centerPanel.add(stop);

    north.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);



    west = new JPanel();
    JLabel temp = new JLabel("°C");
    west.add(temp);

    container.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    container.add(west,BorderLayout.WEST);
    container.add(pan, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.setContentPane(container);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public class ListenForButton implements ActionListener {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if(e.getSource()==ip)
    {
       options.add(address);
       options.add(address_t);
       options.add(port);
       options.add(port_t);
         int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, options, "Please Enter an IP Address and the port wanted", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
         if(result==JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
            {
             if(!address_t.getText().isEmpty())
                {
                    addIp=address_t.getText();
                }
            }

    }
```

And I want the addIP variable be accessible in my JPanel class:

```
public class GraphDisplay extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

double rand, lastrand, max, min, total, degr, average, temp, length;
ArrayList<Double> randL = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> tL = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> dateL = new ArrayList<>();
int lastT = 0;
Color red = new Color(255, 0, 0);
Color green = new Color(0, 200, 0);
Color blue = new Color(0, 0, 200);
Color yellow = new Color(200, 200, 0);
int i, k = 0, inc, j, t;


public GraphDisplay() {
    super();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
```

I copied you just the beginning of the class because the rest isn't interesting for this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options:

- Have the object that holds the information "push" it into the other object. To do this, your Window class would need to hold an instance of the GraphDisplay class, and call a method that GraphDisplay has, say, `setIPaddress(String ip)`, passing in the String into GraphDisplay. Note that the instance hold by Window has to be the visualized GraphDisplay instance, and not any old instance.
- Or you could have GraphDisplay "pull" the information in. Here Window would notify any listeners that the addIP variable has changed, and so the listeners, here this could be the GraphDisplay instance, could call `getAddIP()` from Window and thereby get the new value. To do this, you'd have to use Swing's notification mechanism, such as a ChangeListener or a PropertyChangeListener.